# How to send message to multiple number using arduino and SIM900A mini v3.8.2?

Tags: arduino-uno

I am using this code to send message using Arduino Uno & SIM900A mini v3.8.2 module. But I need to send same message on multiple numbers.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial SIM900A(10,11);
void setup()
{
  SIM900A.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println ("SIM900A Ready");
  delay(100);
  Serial.println ("Type s to send message or r to receive message");
}
void loop()
{
  if (Serial.available()>0)
   switch(Serial.read())
  {
    case 's':
      SendMessage();
      break;
    case 'r':
      RecieveMessage();
      break;
  }
 if (SIM900A.available()>0)
   Serial.write(SIM900A.read());
}
 void SendMessage()
{
  Serial.println ("Sending Message");
  SIM900A.println("AT+CMGF=1");
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println ("Set SMS Number");
  SIM900A.println("AT+CMGS=\"+639176363802\"\r");
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println ("Set SMS Content");
  SIM900A.println("Sample Message");
  delay(100);
  Serial.println ("Finish");
  SIM900A.println((char)26);// ASCII code of CTRL+Z
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println ("Message has been sent");
}
 void RecieveMessage()
{
  Serial.println ("SIM900A SMS");
  delay (1000);
  SIM900A.println("AT+CNMI=2,2,0,0,0");
  delay(1000);
  Serial.write ("Unread Message done");
 }
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Pass the number as a parameter to SendMessage, and call the function multiple times. NB: Many providers will block messages that are sent too rapidly to prevent spamming.

Comment: I'm sorry but can you please elaborate it more because i can't understand it clearly. I'm new at using arduino. Thank you :)